# htaccess 301 redirect rule to remove part of a query string from URLs, but leave the rest

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to find a redirect that will remove part of a query string from a URL, but leave the remaining query string.

Now I can do this fine via a single URL redirect, but there are hundreds of these URLs. So I'm trying to find a rule that might be able to do this for all of them in one fell swoop, so I don't have to make one for each and any new ones will get redirected automatically.

I'm trying to remove `start=0&` from the URLs, here are some examples:

```
www.example.com/products.php?start=0&category=Pens%20Ballpens
```

redirects too:

```
www.example.com/products.php?category=Pens%20Ballpens
```

and

```
www.example.com/products.php?start=0&category=Jackets
```

redirects too:

```
www.example.com/products.php?category=Jackets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your htaccess in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?start=0(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?products\.php$ /products.php?%1%2 [R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works OK for urls without a space in, but when the urls has a space redirects like this:

e.g:

www.xxxxx.co.uk/products.php?start=0&category=Pens%20Ballpens

redirects too:

www.xxxxx.co.uk/products.php?&category=Pens%2520Ballpens

adds %2520 in the urls, rather than %20

Comment: @moobot my bad, see the edit, you need a `NE` flag in the rule.