# .htaccess - remove one variable and 301 redirect, but leave others untouched?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to remove one entire variable (but only if it's equal to 1).  How can I do this?  Basically I want to remove the string "&page=1".  Here's what I mean:

If page=1:

301 redirect from BEFORE to AFTER

BEFORE: https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss&page=1

AFTER: https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss

If page = 2 or any other number EXCEPT 1 (nothing is changed or forwarded - no 301):

BEFORE: https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss&page=2

AFTER: https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss&page=2

I've tried some suggestions and searches, but nothing seems to be working...

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=1$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.fubar.com/search.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&page=1 [R=301,L,END]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=1$
RewriteRule ^ search.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&page=1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on 

# if &page=1
#redirect to remove the &page perm
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?cs=tt&st=ss&page=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect your url from `https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss&page=1` to the same url but without the `page` perameter at the end (ie : `https://www.fubar.com/search.php?cs=tt&st=ss` ) .

Note that `R` is a 302 temporary redirect flag . I am using this just to test the rule and  avoid browser caches. You can change the `R` to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent .

Comment: This works, but if any of the other variables change, it no longer works...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution HERE: [htaccess 301 redirect rule to remove part of a query string from URLs, but leave the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539981/htaccess-301-redirect-rule-to-remove-part-of-a-query-string-from-urls-but-leave))

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?page=1(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?search\.php$ /search.php?%1%2 [R=301,NE]
```